# Selecting a SMPS transformer

Tags: current, transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, high-voltage

I am in the process of selecting a transformer for my SMPS design and need some help in doing so. I am trying to design a universal input - 54 V constant voltage output SMPS.

Looking at the data sheet of this transformer:

[image]

It says the secondary coil can handle 5A @ 24V. Does this apply for both coils 11-13 and 10-12 or only for 10-12? Also would it be possible to draw 2 amps but at 54V~55V instead?

If not, is there a better/more suitable way of finding a transformer for my application?

Comment: It depends on your TBD specs for VA output and VAR loading effects which must derate the power rating as the saturation depends on total current real & reactive.

Comment: No it is not designed for 48V as you suggested. Start with your design specs in detail for surge current and rated load voltage and current. Rectifier Caps are 0 ohm + ESR short circuits on DC startup, so PWM is required to ramp up.

Comment: If you want to buy enough of them most magnetics houses will assist you if you give them your topology and specifications.  Most SMPS transformers are custom.

Answer (score 1):

You have some homework to define unstated assumptions into a design type (presumably some kind of flyback, DCM, Boundary mode, Quasi-Resonant) .

**Note:** <=50 is considered SELV low voltage, Therefore your searches should include high voltage >50V  Wurth does make HV transformers for these, but efficiency is better with a smaller input voltage range, so std. items do not appear to include your input range.  I suggest this may be a steep learning curve for now and you might not have the time to learn well enough to succeed the 1st time.

### May I suggest a buy option for a board?

https://belfuse.com/resources/datasheets/powersolutions/ds-BPS-WLP120-series.pdf  (Mouser or Digikey)

[image]
*(Your lack of design specs was the tell for me to suggest this)*

===============================

Otherwise please learn more design methodologies which includes tradeoffs for optimal performance in EMI, efficiency, cost complexity, stability and learning curve.

This part looks like maybe a good candidate for a 24V flyback supply @ 5A < 100W peak but sub-optimal for 54V 2A with 360Vp input.

There are many design tools available from 6 or more OEM's websites that only require free registration.

e.g.

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t9zNPLkHvjA&t=3s

  - https://www.we-online.com/web/en/electronic_components/willkommen_pbs/Welcome.php
  - https://redexpert.we-online.com/redexpert/#/smodule/31
- https://www.pulseelectronics.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Pulse-Power-BU-Optimize-Flyback-Magnetics.pdf

When in doubt call supplier online.

Perhaps the easiest to use is TI's Power designer with a registered email.
.
https://www.ti.com/design-resources/design-tools-simulation/webench-power-designer.html

[image]

1 of > 6 examples
[image]

### [Wise words from Würth](https://www.we-online.com/web/en/index.php/download/media/07_electronic_components/download_center_1/application_notes_berichte/8_design_tipps_zur_speicherdrosselauswahl/8_Design_Tipps.pdf)

### [www.we-online.com](http://www.we-online.com)
Power Inductors   : 8 Design Tips

https://www.we-online.com

### A practical guide for the selection of power inductors for DC/DC converters

**Switching frequency**

The switching frequency of typical converter ICs on the market is in the range 100 kHz to 2 MHz. First generation regulators operated in the range 30kHz to 55kHz. This leads to the following recommendations:

### DESIGN TIP 1:

**Suitable core materials**

Switching frequency < 100 kHz: Iron powder, ferrite, Superflux, WE-PERM
Switching frequency 100-1000 kHz: Ferrite, Superflux, WE-PERM
Switching frequency > 1000 kHz: Ferrite, WE-PERM

**Inductor current ratings**

The current load for power inductors can be calculated very accurately in terms of DC current load and ripple current load (core losses) using the manufacturers’ simulation software.

The following approach can be chosen as a rough calculation:

### DESIGN TIP 2:

**Inductance value**

 higher inductance – smaller ripple current
 lower inductance – higher ripple current
The ripple current is essential in determining the core losses. Besides the switching frequency, it is therefore an important parameter for minimising the power loss of the power inductor.

Step-up regulator: \$L =\dfrac{(Uout + UD - Uin min) • U2in
}{2 • 0.2 • Iout • (Uout + UD )2 • f}\$

**Type and EMC**

Magnetic shielded power inductors like WE-PD, WE-TPC, WE-DD or WE-HCI are recommended for EMC-critical applications. The shielding prevents uncontrolled magnetic coupling of the windings with neighbouring conductor tracks or components.

**Output L-C filter**

An L-C filter at the DC converter output is recommended if a low noise output voltage is required. The components can be selected as follows [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9UsX.png):

Nominal current of the inductor: **Iin = Iout**
Maximum coil current: Imax = 1.5 x IN

**Step-up regulator:**

Nominal current of the inductor: I_{in }= (U_{out} / U_{in}) * I_{out   }$
Maximum coil current: Imax = 2 x IN

### DESIGN TIP 3:

- Please observe the definitions for the data sheet specifications. The nominal current for power inductors is usually linked to the specified self-heating with
  DC current
  – here self-heating of +40°C is common at the nominal current.
- According to semiconductor manufacturers‘ recommendations, the saturation current is the point at which the inductance value has fallen by 10 %.
- Unfortunately, this is not a standard value for power inductor data sheet specifications and often leads to misinterpretation among users.
  DC resistance
- Once the required values for inductance L and inductor currents are calculated, you select a power inductor with the minimum possible DC resistance.

**- Here the demands are often counteractive:**

- Small size, high energy storage density and low DC resistance.

Using suitable winding methods and new series, such as the Würth Elektronik WE-HCI and WE-PDF flat-wire inductors, this ideal case is very close to realisation.

The data sheet definition must also be observed here:
Is the DC resistance specified as a typical value or as the max. value required for calculating the circuit under worst case conditions?

### DESIGN TIP 4:

DC resistance with the same size
 higher inductance – higher DC resistance
 lower inductance – lower DC resistance
 same inductance for a shielded inductor – lower DC resistance
The DC resistance is essential in determining the wire heating losses; this is another important parameter for minimising the power loss of the power inductor.

Inductance value

If there is no application note or software available, inductance can be calculated using the following rule-of-thumb formula:

### Step-down regulator:

\$L = \dfrac{(U_{in max} - U_{out}) • (U_{out} + U_D)}{(U_{in max} + U_D) • 0.3 • I_{out} • f}\$

- with the ripple current factors 0.2 to 0.4 (selected as 0.2 and 0.3 in this example). Iout is the operating current of the circuit to be supplied, Uout the output voltage and Uin the input voltage, f is the switching frequency of the regulator IC.
- Standard values for inductance L can be selected on the basis of the calculated value. If, for example, the value 37.36 μH is obtained as the result
  – you would select the standard values 33 μH, 39 μH and possibly also
  47 μH for testing.

### DESIGN TIP 5:

- Use a magnetically shielded power inductor if at all possible. Do not route any conductor tracks under the component and do not place any circuit boards directly above the component, as this could give rise to coupling via the air gap remaining.
- Unshielded power inductors like WE-PD2 can be used for uncritical applications or for low power circuits.
- Many packaging series can even be changed from shielded to unshielded versions while maintaining solder pad compatibility.

### DESIGN TIP 6:

- Advantage of magnetically shielded inductors of the same type:

  -  higher AL value, therefore lower DC resistances for the same inductance = lower wire losses.
- Disadvantage of magnetically shielded inductors of the same type:

  -  slightly increased core losses due to a larger core volume.
  - Given correct dimensioning the core losses remain low.

### DESIGN TIP 7:

 Select cut-off frequency at 1/10 of the switching regulator frequency
 Select output capacitor (e.g. 22 μF)
 Calculate inductance

- \$L = \dfrac{1}{ (2π • f)^2  C}\$
   slightly increased core losses due to a larger core volume. Given correct dimensioning the core losses remain low from DC converter

### DESIGN TIP 8:

**Ripple measurements**

- Unfortunately, for high frequency measurements, this ground clip can pick-up high frequency noise and erroneously inject it into the measured output ripple.
- To properly measure ripple on either input or output of a switching regulator, a proper ring in Tipp measurement is required. Standard oscilloscope probes come with a grounding clip, or a long wire with an alligator clip. Unfortunately, for high frequency measurements, this ground clip can pick-up high frequency noise and erroneously inject it into the measured output ripple.

**( I prefer to use AC coupled coax to 50 Ohm load on DSO for textbook ripple waveforms)**

The standard evaluation board accommodates a home made version by providing probe points for both the input and output supplies and their respective grounds.

N.B. This requires the removing of the oscilloscope probe sheath and ground clip from a standard oscilloscope probe and wrapping a non-shielded bus wire around the oscilloscope probe. If there does not happen to be any non shielded bus wire immediately available, the leads from axial resistors will work. By maintaining the shortest possible ground lengths on the oscilloscope probe, true ripple measurements can be obtained.

### Summary

The power inductor selection steps described are based on the design tips given in this article and are linked to the data sheet specifications. Not only the relevant design software from the semiconductor manufacturer serves to reduce development times. With the software Component Selector you get a tool which identifies very quick the right inductance for a buck or a boost converter. As a matter of course power inductors from Würth Elektronik are also listed in the leading semiconductor manufacturers‘ software solutions and hence they are immediately available for inclusion in the simulations. Correspondingly assembled design kits help optimise prototypes.

Magnetically shielded power inductors should be deployed for EMC-critical applications.

References:
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9UsX.png) Schramm, C.; DC-Wandler: Ausgangsspannung „säubern“
[DC converters: “clean up” output voltage]; ELEKTRONIK, Issue 23/2001. pg. 88ff
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wAnC.png) Gerfer, A.; Rall, B.; Zenkner, H.: Trilogy of Magnetics, 4th extended edition
2009, Swiridoff Verlag, ISBN 978-3-89929-157-5
[4](https://www.we-online.com/web/en/index.php/download/media/07_electronic_components/download_center_1/application_notes_berichte/8_design_tipps_zur_speicherdrosselauswahl/8_Design_Tipps.pdf) Würth Elektronik, Component Selector, download at:
https://www.we-online.com/component-selector
[4](https://www.we-online.com/web/en/index.php/download/media/07_electronic_components/download_center_1/application_notes_berichte/8_design_tipps_zur_speicherdrosselauswahl/8_Design_Tipps.pdf) Linear Technology Switcher CAD III /LTspice IV, download at:
https://www.linear.com/ltspice
[5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mo38F.png) Texas Instruments, Switcher Pro, download at:
https://www.ti.com/switcherpro
[6] Exar, Power Lab, download at:
https://www.exar.com/powerlab
[7] TI , WEBENCH, download (if still avail) at:
https://www.ti.com/design-resources/design-tools-simulation/webench-power-designer.html

wurth [www.we-online.com](http://www.we-online.com)

### **P.S. If you REALLY serious about this design requirement, I suggest you buy our resident expert's latest book who goes by a nom-de-plume here.**

https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Spice.htm

DIY 5 minute approach still needs work.
54Vdc 2A out
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response - I think I am looking at a flyback transformer in my case - as it is most commonly used in switched mode power supplies

Comment: I also think the problem I am encountering is that none of the wurth electronics smps transformers go to a high voltage as 54 V

Comment: Where are your specs?. Load range steady , Step un/load max , start surge current max?  voltage error max?  Efficiency, operating temp etc etc

Comment: You need a custom design not shown in the Wurth catalog for a 54V 2Adc supply with TBD input voltage range

Comment: Would it be possible and reasonable to add a small 6V 2A SMPS to a standard 48V 2A supply to get the 54 VDC output needed?